# Getting lots of CloudKit errors (500) all of a sudden

Tags: cloudkit

Nearly everything my app does in CloudKit now returns this error:

```
<CKError 0x14ecff70: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2001); "Request failed with http status code 500">
(lldb) po [error userInfo]
{
    CKDHTTPHeaders =     {
        Connection = close;
        "Content-Length" = 0;
        "X-Apple-Request-UUID" = "F8E4C91A-5F72-4792-9F13-BB5FBB10BA8E";
        "X-Responding-Instance" = "ckdatabaseservice:32400203:mr11p24ic-ztbu11100101:8103:15B153:16274";
    };
    CKHTTPStatus = 500;
    NSDebugDescription = "CKInternalErrorDomain: 2001";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Request failed with http status code 500";
    NSUnderlyingError = "<CKError 0x14d5af70: \"Unknown Error\" (2001)>";
}
```

Any ideas why this could be happening? I'm tempted to blame it on temporary CloudKit server issues (which is how I would want to interpret an error 500)...but I don't know if that's appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug on the iCloud server that's affecting your container. I've grabbed logs from that request and the server team will clean up your container soon. In the meantime you can use a different container name for testing.

If you'd like to file a radar for this we can let you know when the container gets cleaned up.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Did not expect this definitive of an answer! (Just curious: was there something I might have done to create this condition? Just so I can avoid it in the near term...?)

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong on your side. It was a server bug due to some improperly cached data that affected a couple of containers. We did one scan to clean up all of the containers, but it looks like yours slipped through the cracks. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: The container should be cleaned up now. Let me know if you have any more issues with it.

Comment: I've recently had the same issue, is there a way of getting my cache cleaned too? :)

Comment: All of the containers should have gotten cleaned up at once, so you might be seeing a different issue. Can you file a radar with your container identifier and logs from https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/icloud/#icloud-drive

Comment: @farktronix I've started having an issue with my server-to-server connection. Been getting `500` errors throughout the day. The link you posted in your last comment only refers to iOS and macOS, anything when it comes to server-to-server?

Comment: @Baza207 A 500 error might just mean the iCloud servers are temporarily down. If this problem persists I would recommend opening a radar at bugreport.apple.com and including your container name and a copy of the server's response so the server team can look at their logs to see what happened.

Comment: @farktronix Will do, thanks. Don't seem to be getting them today, so perhaps it was a temporary thing (updating for next week perhaps ).